# How to use JMeter to record user input

Tags: jmeter

How to record user input parameters using JMeter? I tried to use the record controller and follow through the tutorials, all the records are only http get requests without any post input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Properly configured JMeter captures **all** network activity between browser and application under test, the fact you don't see POST requests might indicate one of the following:

1. Browser simply doesn't make any POST requests, i.e. your application is designed to operate only GET HTTP Request types
2. Your JMeter configuration is not correct, i.e. your application uses [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https). In this case you need to perform some extra configuration so JMeter could intercept, decrypt and record HTTPS requests:

   - make sure your browser is configured to use proxy for **all** protocols

     [image: JMeter proxy for all protocols]
   - make sure you install JMeter's self-signed certificate to your browser. The file name is `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it is being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start JMeter Proxy Server

     [image: JMeter Install certificate]

More information:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (pay attention to **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter)
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)